# Освободить файл от процесса - как усовершенствовать этот код?

Tags: c++, winapi

При обходе каталогов программа пытается освобождать файлы, занятые процессами, для последующей операции над ними.
Соединил две функции - вроде работает. Но я на стадии обучения и понимаю, что решение можно было написать лучше.

Посоветуйте более правильный вариант/корректировку. Я только постигаю **С++** и ошибаюсь очень часто, поэтому нуждаюсь в ваших мудрых советах.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <restartmanager.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Rstrtmgr.lib")

using namespace std;

using String_t  = std::string;
using WString_t = std::wstring;

bool FinishProcess(const WString_t&& process_name) 
{
    auto case_in_sens_string_compare = [&](const WString_t& str1, const WString_t& str2) noexcept
    {
        return ((str1.size() == str2.size()) &&
            std::equal(begin(str1), end(str1), begin(str2), [](wchar_t c1, wchar_t c2)
                {
                    if (c1 == c2)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else if (std::toupper(c1) == std::toupper(c2))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
        ));
    };

    if (!process_name.empty())
    {
        HANDLE snapshot = ::CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
        if (snapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            PROCESSENTRY32 pe = { 0 };
            pe.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

            if (::Process32First(snapshot, &pe))
            {
                do
                {
                    if (case_in_sens_string_compare(process_name, pe.szExeFile))
                    {
                        HANDLE hp = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, 0, (DWORD)pe.th32ProcessID);
                        if (hp)
                        {
                            TerminateProcess(hp, 0);
                            CloseHandle(hp);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                } while (::Process32Next(snapshot, &pe));
            }
            ::CloseHandle(snapshot);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void FreeProcess(const WCHAR* file) 
{
    DWORD hSess = 0;
    WCHAR key[50] = L"MySession";
    DWORD res;

    res = RmStartSession(&hSess, 0, key);

    if (res != 0) 
    {
        // Cannot start session
        return;
    }

    LPCWSTR filenames[] = { file };
    res = RmRegisterResources(hSess, 1, filenames, 0, NULL, 0, NULL);

    if (res != 0) 
    {
        // Cannot register resource
        return;
    }

    UINT procInfoNeeded;
    UINT procInfo = 10;
    DWORD rebootReasons;
    RM_PROCESS_INFO info[10];
    res = RmGetList(hSess, &procInfoNeeded, &procInfo, info, &rebootReasons);

    if (res != 0) 
    {
        // Cannot get list of processes
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < procInfo; i++) 
    {
        if (!FinishProcess(info[i].strAppName)) 
        {
            HANDLE hp = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, 0, info[i].Process.dwProcessId);

            if (hp)
            {
                TerminateProcess(hp, 0);
                CloseHandle(hp);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    FreeProcess(L"C:\\Test\\www.docx");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не глядя натравливать TerminateProcess на любой процесс, который держит файл, весьма сомнительная идея. Помимо обычного приложения, файл может быть открыт системной службой. Например, если файл лежит в общей сетевой папке и открыт с другого компьютера, ваш код прибьет службу общих файлов. Собственно, Restart Manager для того и создан, чтобы корректно обрабатывать подобные ситуации. Вместо TerminateProcess используйте RmShutdown и RmRestart:

```
void FreeProcess(const WCHAR* file)
{
    DWORD hSess = 0;
    WCHAR key[50] = L"MySession";
    DWORD res;

    res = RmStartSession(&hSess, 0, key);

    if (res != 0)
    {
        // Cannot start session
        return;
    }

    LPCWSTR filenames[] = { file };
    res = RmRegisterResources(hSess, 1, filenames, 0, NULL, 0, NULL);

    if (res != 0)
    {
        // Cannot register resource
        RmEndSession(hSess);
        return;
    }

    UINT procInfoNeeded;
    UINT procInfo = 10;
    DWORD rebootReasons;
    RM_PROCESS_INFO info[10];
    res = RmGetList(hSess, &procInfoNeeded, &procInfo, info, &rebootReasons);

    if (res != 0)
    {
        // Cannot get list of processes
        RmEndSession(hSess);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < procInfo; i++)
        wprintf(L"%u: %s\n", info[i].Process.dwProcessId, info[i].strAppName);

    res=RmShutdown(hSess, RmForceShutdown, NULL); //останавливаем процесс

    if (res != 0)
    {
        fputws(L"RmShutdown failed",stdout);
        RmEndSession(hSess);
        return;
    }

    //выполняем необходимые операции с файлом...

    RmRestart(hSess, 0, NULL); //перезапускаем процесс, если это поддерживается

    RmEndSession(hSess);
}
```

Comment: MSDN.WhiteKnight :: Спасибо за дельный и конструктивный совет с подробным примером!

Comment: Обнаружилось интересное: если открыты два файла docx и xlsx, то завершается только процесс Word, а процесс Exel продолжает работу. С чем это связано?

Comment: @Алекс в моем коде при каждом вызове FreeProcess идет попытка создать сессию с именем "MySession". Вторая и последующие попытки упадут с ошибкой, так как сессия с таким именем уже существует. Я добавлю удаление сессии, но вообще создавать сессию каждый раз не обязательно.

Comment: MSDN.WhiteKnight :: Спасибо!.. С Вами я многое для себя прояснил касательно стоящей передо мной задачи.